# Creating a compartive object in R from two dataframes for comparitive phylogenetics

Tags: r, dataframe, phylogeny

I'm trying to read in two dataframes into a comparitive object so I can plot them using pgls.

I'm not sure what the error being returned means, and how to go about getting rid of it.

My code:

```
library(ape)
library(geiger)
library(caper)

taxatree <- read.nexus("taxonomyforzeldospecies.nex")
LWEVIYRcombodata <- read.csv("LWEVIYR.csv")


LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS <-data.frame(LWEVIYRcombodata$Sum.of.percentage,OGT=LWEVIYRcombodata$OGT, Species=LWEVIYRcombodata$Species)

comp.dat <- comparative.data(taxatree, LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS, "Species")
```

Returns error:

```
> comp.dat <- comparative.data(taxatree, LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS, 'Species')
Error in if (tabulate(phy$edge[, 1])[ntips + 1] > 2) FALSE else TRUE : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Check the `?comparative.data` help page. The first parameter must be a phylogeny (an object of class "phylo"), not a data.frame. Those errors are because you are passing in the wrong type of object.

Comment: Nexus files are phylogenies, maybe it just doesn't accept that filetype though?

Comment: You are right. I misread that. Sorry. It would be easier to say what's going in for sure with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can run the code to see what's going on. Right not since we don't have the input files we just have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that I was using a nexus file, although `?comparitive.data` does not specify which phylo objects it should use, newick trees seem to work fine, whereas nexus files do not.

Answer (score 0):

This might come from your data set and your phylogeny having some discrepancies that `comparative.data` struggles to handle (by the look of the error message).

You can try cleaning both the data set and the tree using `dispRity::clean.data`:

```
library(dispRity)

## Reading the data
taxatree <- read.nexus("taxonomyforzeldospecies.nex")
LWEVIYRcombodata <- read.csv("LWEVIYR.csv")
LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS <- data.frame(LWEVIYRcombodata$Sum.of.percentage,OGT=LWEVIYRcombodata$OGT, Species=LWEVIYRcombodata$Species)

## Cleaning the data
cleaned_data <- clean.data(LWEVIYRcombodataPGLS, taxatree)

## Preparing the comparative data object
comp.dat <- comparative.data(cleaned_data$tree, cleaned_data$data, "Species")
```

However, as @MrFlick suggests, it's hard to know if that solves the problem without a reproducible example.

Comment: When trying to run this, I get :

`Error in comparative.data(cleaned_data$tree, cleaned_data$data, "Species")` `:` 
  `'cleaned_data$tree' not of class 'phylo'`

Although that happens even if I use a newick tree, which does work with my original code, not sure what's going on here!

Comment: You might have multiple trees in your newick file. Did you try `class(taxatree)` and `class(cleaned_data$tree)`? If they are `multiPhylo` you might want to select only the one tree (`one_tree <- cleaned_data$tree[[1]]`) or use a multiple tree approach (e.g. [mulTree](https://github.com/TGuillerme/mulTree)).